# python embedding in C : define the python script as a C string?

Tags: python, c, embedding

I would like to invoke the following python script in C :

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import parser

def evaluate(text):
   code = parser.expr(text).compile()
   return eval(code)
```

as explained in the following page https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html, i can call this script from C using the pwd(path) of the file.

However, i would like to know if it's possible to not load the script by calling python on a C string directly, defining the script.

For example, i would like to let's say i put :

```
#define PYTHON_SCRIPT ((char*)(\      
  import parser\  
  \                    
  def evaluate(text):\   
    code = parser.expr(text).compile()\  
    return eval(code)\ 
  ))
```

is it possible to call the python interpreter directly on that string?

Indeed, knowing that i need to pass text as a variable, i can't use this Pyrun_SimpleString function, and i was not able to find something to answer this question.

Comment: There is no `PyRun_FromString` function in the Python-C-API. Do you mean `PyRun_SimpleString`? Why can't you use it? It is one possible way to execute Python in C.

Comment: ah yes indeed, i correct it. The problem with PyRun_SimpleString is that it seems to not take variables as arguments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment there is no `Pyrun_SimpleString`. How to execute Python functions from C is covered [here](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#calling-python-functions-from-c). One way to do it:

1. Compile your script using `Py_CompileString`
2. Create a dictionary for globals/locals.
3. Extract the function from your globals dict by using `PyDict_GetItemString(name)`
4. Build your arguments tuple with `PyArg_ParseTuple`
5. Execute your function object by using `PyObject_CallFunction`.

Comment: thanks i was able to do what i wanted using your answer

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Weave](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/weave.html), it allows you to include C code directly in Python code.

Comment: thank you, but i want to do the opposite : calling python within C ^^